# How to prevent re-rendering when a particular state changes in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm randomizing the answers for my quiz app. It does randomizing the answers but when any answer is selected, it randomize the answers again.

```
     {questions[currentQuestion].options
          .slice(0, questions[currentQuestion].options.length - 1)
          .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
          .map((answer, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={selectedAnswerHandler.bind(
                this,
                answer.id,
                answer.answerText
              )}
              key={index}
            >
              <View
                style={
                  selectedAnwserId === answer.id
                    ? styles.selectedAnswerTab
                    : styles.answerTab
                }
              >
                <Text
                  style={
                    selectedAnwserId === answer.id
                      ? [styles.answerText, { color: color.secondaryColor }]
                      : styles.answerText
                  }
                >
                  {answer.answerText}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
```

Here is the selectedAnswerHandler

```
  const selectedAnswerHandler = (ansId, answer) => {
    setSelectedAnswerId(ansId);
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
  };
```

I know its randomizing again because state is changing and its re-rendering. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You put the order in state (via `useState`), so that it's not random every single render, and you get to choose when to set a new order in that state.

Answer (score 0):

Learn useEffect and its dependency array. for eg.

Well, this may not be the exact correct answer but will give a clear idea.

```
useEffect(()=>{
selectedAnswerHandler(ansId, answer)
},[ansId, answer])
```

this will only call selectedAnswerHandler when either one of ansId, answer changes. ansId, answer can be your state or anything.

Comment: ansId and answer is only changing when user is selecting an answer but it results in re-rendering which is randomizing the answers again I want to prevent this

Comment: show more code.

Comment: answers should only be randomized once, not again and again on selecting answers.

Comment: my code is not exactly correct, as when answer changes then function is called, and that function changes the state. so it will again run.  This was just to give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, whenever the component is rendered, you're randomizing the questions again and again.

You should generate them one and cache them using `useState` or `useMemo`, i.e.:

```js
const [questions, setNextQuestions] = useState(() => (
  /* generate a bunch of random questions */
  /* these will be consistent the entire time the component is on screen */
));

return questions.map(
  ({id, ...questionProps}: Question) => <Question key={id} {...questionProps} />,
);
```

If you find it's still changing the questions when you don't want them to, it's a suggestion that the `questions` have a greater lifetime than the component itself, and therefore the componet shouldn't be the one responsible for generating the questions; it should probably be the parent. If this is the case, you should pass questions as a prop or via [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

**Extra performance tips:**

It looks like you're passing the `index` of iteration to the `key` prop. If you recreate the array, all the questions get shuffled, and assigned to new indexes, which trashes a bunch of render state.

If you provide each question with a unique `key` attribute and use *this* as the `key` prop, regardless of how you shuffle the questions will still render gracefully.

By the way, you can also prevent excessive re-renders by not allocating a new function handler every time your component state is changed. This can be done via `useCallback`:

```js
 const selectedAnswerHandler = React.useCallback((ansId, answer) => {
    setSelectedAnswerId(ansId);
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
 }, [/* any render variables this function should be sensitive to */]);
```

Basically try to avoid allocation wherever possible. If you don't the loss of performance is noticeable, particularly on Android.